# Can plunker save to github?

Tags: git, github, plunker

Can I make projects on plnkr.co and save them to github? 
Plnkr is perfect to present javascript projects and enables instant collaborative developements. It will be very helpful if I can export from plnkr.co to github.
Is this possible? then how?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Apparently not.

You have similar "synchronization" requests expressed in, for instance, [issue 28](https://github.com/filearts/plunker/issues/28), which resulted in scripts like [**plunk_it**](https://github.com/r26D/plunk_it).

The idea is to have:

- your files in your local repo (that you can push to GitHub)
- a way to send those same files to plunker

The author of plunker suggests those alternatives:

> I can suggest to you three alternative ways of getting your code onto Plunker that may or may not better suit your workflow:
>
> - Create a POST payload (in the same way you do in [r26D/plunk_id]) and send that to http://plnkr.co/edit/ (or http://beta.plnkr.co if you're feeling adventurous).
>     That is what is used by the AngularJS documentation (see the Edit button on: http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.directive:ngReadonly).
> - Sync your snippets with Gist and then use import links for your users. This would use the same mechanism as most of the current templates on Plunker.
>     To use, create a form in an iframe whose post body would correspond to the Plunk schema you've already discovered and post that iframe to http://plnkr.co/edit/gist: with `target="_blank | _self"`.
> - Create a new importer schema for directories in a Github repository. This is something I've been wanting to add but never got around do.
>     The way the importers work can be seen in: https://github.com/filearts/plunker_www/blob/master/assets/js/services/importer.coffee
>
> Now, the major caveat of all of these proposed approaches is that you would not be able to see a listing of forks from your original code. This may be something you want. In fact, there will soon (read: next few months-ish) be more information on plunk histories. Instead of a single fork_of attribute, there will be a history array or something of the sort.
>
> Also, a second caveat is that when I deploy the discussion pane (see: http://beta.plnkr.co/sMXKW6), none of the proposed approaches would support commenting as comments would only be enabled for saved plunks.

Comment: Thank you, like you say, apparently not.

Comment: Did it worked????  I am trying something similar on https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51389437/send-and-get-data-from-code-editor-like-plunker-embedded

Comment: @Vonc Thanks a lot, if you have any updated regarding this problem, could be in another tool similar to plunker like jsbin or jsfiddle, please let me know. We can even host the code editor in our servers, but I believe it would take a long time to do it.